# Javascript - Dynamically creates number of arrays within a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have one variable `$arrayQuantity` which has a dynamic value. It specifies the number of 
`item` arrays to be created inside the `$itemsContainer` array when the page loads.

For instance:

```
   //Here I specified to create 3 `item` arrays inside the *itemsContainer* array.
   //The arrays to be created within the *itemsContainer*, contains two
   //dynamic values, `object_name` and `quantity`.

   var object_name;
   var quantity;
   var item = [object_name, quantity];
   var arrayQuantity = 3; 
   var itemsContainer = [];

   //Below is the array created filled with dynamic data.
   itemsContainer = [["Chair", "2"]["Table", "5"]["Glass", "8"]];
```

What's the way to approach this solution?

**EDIT :**

The dynamic data is assigned for `object_name` and `quantity` according to what button is pressed on the screen. (Not relevant for the question).

If the `object_name` is existent within the array, only the `quantity` has to be updated (prevent duplicate `object_name`.

Comment: might be easier to use an object instead of an array given your requirements of updating

Answer (score 0):

While I am unsure where you are getting the data from to assign to the values `object_name` and `quantity`... You can probably just create a loop that iterates `arrayQuantity` number of times and pushes a new array into `itemsContainer`.

```
var arrayQuantity = 3;
var itemsContainer = [];

for(var i=0; i < arrayQuantity; i++) {
    var arrItem = ["itemName", Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)];
    itemsContainer.push(arrItem);
}

console.log(itemsContainer);
```

Without knowing where you get your values from I hope this helps put you in the right direction.

[>> JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tpa09vp5/)

-mbp

Answer (score 0):

You create the inner array, and push it into the outer array

```
var objs = ["Chair", "Table", "Glass"];   
var quantities = ["2", "5", "8"]
var itemsContainer = [];
var arrayQuantity = 3; 
for (var i = 0; i < arrayQuantity; i++) {
    var object_name = objs[i];
    var quantity = quantities[i];
    var item = [object_name, quantity];
    itemsContainer.push(item);
}
console.log(itemsContainer);
```

Here's a slightly more advanced way to do it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
var objs = ["Chair", "Table", "Glass"];   
var quantities = ["2", "5", "8"]
var itemsContainer = objs.map(function(obj, index){
    return [obj, quantities[index]];
});
```

If you want to update a specific item, you can do the following

```
var object_name = "Chair";
var quantity = "99999";
for (var i = 0; i < itemsContainer.length; i++) {
    if (itemsContainer[i][0] === object_name) {
        itemsContainer[i][1] = quantity;
    }
}
```